# SQL - count relation instances

Tags: sql

I have this SQL diagram:

[image]

I want to get all the subscribers that likes exactly 0 reports.

started by: `SELECT * FROM subscriber HAVING count(...)`

How do I count how many reporters a subscriber likes?

A relationship should get it's own table in an SQL database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not completely sure I understand your last question, but this sounds like a nice time for a `NOT IN` clause.

```
SELECT *
FROM Subscriber
WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT SubscriberId
                 FROM Likes
                     INNER JOIN Reporter ON Reporter.Id = Likes.ReporterId)
```

The inner query there simply finds all the subscriber ids that have been reported, then the outer one grabs all the other ones. You might be able to improve efficiency of this query by changing that `INNER JOIN` to another `IN`, but you'd have to play with it.

As far as the task of counting them, I'd probably just do this. You could group and such, but this is simple,

```
SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT(*)
           FROM Likes
               INNER JOIN Reporter ON Reporter.Id = Likes.ReporterId
           WHERE Likes.SubscriberId = Subscriber.Id) AS ReportersCount
FROM Subscriber
```

Note that for your listed task of finding the ones with zero reporters, the first query will be faster, because it will be able to short-circuit, rather than having to count every reporter for every row. Of course, neither should be too bad as long as you've got the appropriate indexes.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM subscriber WHERE su_phone NOT IN (SELECT su_phone FROM likes INNER JOIN reporter ON reporter.re_id = likes.re_id)` would do the work?

Comment: @billie I think so. It's best to try it, but as I understand your table structure and question, that looks reasonable.